# SAPUI5 ColumnListItem, icon need to be displayed on the left hand side

Tags: sapui5

I'm using table and using this property.

```
<ColumnListItem type="Detail" detailPress="onShowItemEditDialog">
```

I want the place the icon on the left side.
Because I use responsivePopover.The popover is opening on the right side.
I think I will change the table elements in this popover.
Or is there another way to change the elements of the table?
What can be done for table edit?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can build your own ListItem.

```
<List headerText="Custom Content" mode="Delete" items="{path: '/ProductCollection'}" >
    <CustomListItem>
        <HBox>
            <core:Icon size="2rem" src="sap-icon://attachment-photo" class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" />
            <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" >
                <Link text="{Name}" target="{ProductPicUrl}" press="handlePress"/>
                <Label text="{ProductId}"/>
            </VBox>
        </HBox>
    </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

This example is taken from: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.CustomListItem/code

Answer (score 0):

> A little tweak worked for me. Use the below code appropriately.

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    $( "thead .sapMListTblNavCol" ).insertAfter( "thead .sapMListTblHighlightCol" );
    $( "tbody .sapMListTblNavCol" ).insertAfter( "tbody .sapMListTblHighlightCell" );
},
```